# typedi + fastify - initialize service asynchronously

Tags: node.js, typescript, fastify

I'm working on a nodejs fastify based app service and using typedi for dependency injection.

Some services I use need async initialization.

MyService.ts

```
export class MyService {
   constructor() {

   }

   public async init() {
     ....
   }
}
```

I am trying to initialize the service at application startup so that any service doing Container.get(MyService) gets this initialized instance of MyService

app.ts

```
export default async function(fastify: FastifyInstance, opts: Options, next: Function) {
  // This loads everything under routes 
  fastify.register(autoload, {
    dir: path.join(__dirname, "routes"),
    options: opts,
    includeTypeScript: true,
  });

  await Container.get(MyService);

  next();
}
```

server.ts

```
import app from "./app";

const server = fastify({
  logger: logger
});

server.register(oas, docs);

server.register(app);

server.ready(err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  server.oas();
});

server.listen(config.port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      server.log.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    server.log.info(`server listening on ${server.server.address()}`);
  });
  
export default server;
```

My attempt to initialize MyService is failing.

```
MissingProvidedServiceTypeError [ServiceNotFoundError]: Cannot determine a class of the requesting service "undefined"
```

Any hints to what I'm doing wrong?  I'm new to nodejs and would really appreciate sample code that is correct for this scenario.

Edit
I tried import

```
  Container.import([CmkeService]);
```

MissingProvidedServiceTypeError [ServiceNotFoundError]: Cannot determine a class of the requesting service "undefined"

Comment: you must not use `next` with `async` function in fastify (`app.ts`). Did you import the `MyService` class in the file?

Comment: I tried and added the result in edit as well. I'm getting error - MissingProvidedServiceTypeError [ServiceNotFoundError]: Cannot determine a class of the requesting service "undefined"

Comment: what is the import of `Container`? you are missing the [`type`](https://github.com/typestack/typedi/blob/ba2d73f245ec92f8d67538e2409ec55d2c5cdb7d/src/ContainerInstance.ts#L296)

Comment: Did it solve the issue?

Comment: yes. thank you. it is solved.

Comment: I have the same problem.. I didn't quite understand what you did. Where did you add the type? Could you post a solution?

Comment: For me the issue was I was trying to use constructor injection. That didn't work. Property injection worked.